# SQL Update Query Not updating Simple Record

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi I am using simple update query to update the password of a Admin login table it is not giving me any kind of error but it is not updating my record also.
please tell me what can be the problem
I am using Visual Studio 2012 | SQL SERVER 2008.
here is the Code.

```
 protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            obj.OpenConection();
            obj.ExecuteQueries("Update Admin_Login set Username='" + TextUsername.Text + "',Password='" + TextPassword.Text + "' where Username='" + TextUsername.Text + "'");
            obj.CloseConnection();
        }
```

=> ExecuteQueries() here is a function to execute different queries working fine every where even on other update queries but not here.

Comment: SQL looks OK.  You said you wanted to update the password, but your SQL is also updating the username.  Is that intended?  Maybe that's why you're not finding the changed results.

Comment: Please do not concatenate SQL queries - use prepared statements.

Comment: If you continue to use a string to build your SQL (as opposed to doing Siyual's excellent suggestion) build the SQL into a string, then log or print out the resulting string, so we (and you) can see it.

Comment: @Joe I tried by Updating only password that is also not working i can't understand what is the error. :(

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what the actual string is that's being executed. Copy the value, paste it into your DB engine and see if the command executes correctly there to determine if the code is the problem or the DB is.

Comment: What schema is Admin_Login in?  maybe you need to specify:  [SchemaName].[Admin_Login] in your SQL statement

Comment: btw... are you getting any actual error messages?  or, just no records are being updated?

Comment: Is there any leading/trailing whitespace in the user name?  Is your database case-sensitive?

Comment: btw... regarding updating only the password.  If you only need to update the password, then don't update the username.  I'm not saying that is your problem, but if it is not needed to be updated, then don't update it.  You already proved that wasn't the issue.  There's obviously other stuff going on here.